# Sandbox paypal Account Deleted, But Still exist?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I deleted my paypal account from developer.paypal.com->Sandbox->Accounts

But when I try to create a new account in sandbox Accounts, It is giving me a message that email id exist.!

If it is deleted from sandbox account, why it is showing me the message that "email exist".

Please give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Please file a ticket to PayPal MTS team: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ with the sandbox account email address, error message screenshot. Then PayPal MTS team will help you further.